# How to fix "While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field" error

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

Getting InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field. error when parsing Protobuf

Not sure why parsing failing ever though I can see the output if I call response.getContentAsString() method on response object.

my Proto file:

```
syntax = "proto2";
package  com.test.protocol;

option java_package = "com.test.protocol.v1";
option java_outer_classname = "Test1";

message Test2 {
    required int64 id                  = 1;
    required string value               = 2
}
```

I wrote API to return the Proto response which looks like below

```
final Test2.Builder builder = TEST2.newBuilder();
builder.setId(1);
builder.setValue("1");
return builder.build();
```

My API will return the below output

```
{"id": 1,"value": "1"}
```

I'm trying to call the API and parse it back to Test2 as below

```
import com.test.protocol.v1.Test1.Test2;

final Test2 result = Test2.parseFrom(response.getContentAsByteArray());
```

getting the error in the above step If I debug and try to print response.getContentAsString(), I'm getting correct output as below but parsing is failing.

```
{"id": 1,"value": "1"}
```

Comment: Could you try parseDelimitedFrom?

Comment: @tijn167: but  parseDelimitedFrom accept only InputStream as parameter, here I have a string..

Shall I try like below and then pass this input stream to parseDelimitedFrom ?

InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(exampleString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

Comment: but this json as bytes is not the same as protobuf payload bytes, protobuf does not recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

For your message, the serialized form should be the following 5 bytes `08-01-12-01-31`.<sup>1</sup> The `parseFrom(byte[])` method expect such an encoding. As you give it a JSON, it misinterpret characters in the string and fails. For example, `'{'` means starting a group (this feature is deprecated) with tag 15.

I am going to assume you are using a web framework. You provide a protobuf message for the response in the server, and the framework sends the JSON representation to the client.

For the client to consume the JSON representation, you can use the following code.

```
JsonFormat.parser().merge(theJsonString, Test2.newBuilder())
```

Of course then you are not "using protobuf". Instead you are merely using protobuf generated classes.

---

1. For more the information of the encoding, see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) and try out the [decoder](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode).